# ASP.NET WebApi - Multiple GET actions in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have `Users` controller and basic REST pattern is working just fine. However I need one additional pattern `users/{id}/usergroups` that will return all user groups for that user.

What would be the best way to implement this since I imagine I will need similar routes on many more controllers. Just default ones are not enough...

### Error

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   Api.Models.Users.User GetUser(Int32) on type Api.Controllers.UsersController
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Api.Models.Users.UserGroup] GetUserGroups(Int32) on type Api.Controllers.UsersController

### Code

```
// GET api/Users
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()

// GET api/Users/5
public User GetUser(int id) // THIS IS CONFLICT 1

// PUT api/Users/5
public HttpResponseMessage PutUser(int id, User user)

// POST api/Users
public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)

// DELETE api/Users/5
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteUser(int id)

// GET api/Users/5/UserGroups
public IEnumerable<UserGroup> GetUserGroups(int id)  // THIS IS CONFLICT 2
```

### Edit 1

I did what *amhed* suggested and it doesn't solve the issue.

```
// GET api/Users/5
[HttpGet, ActionName("getuser")]
public User GetUser(int id) // THIS STILL DOES NOT WORK

// GET api/Users/5/UserGroups
[HttpGet, ActionName("usergroups")]
public IEnumerable<UserGroup> GetUserGroups(int id) // THIS WORKS

// ROUTES
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Can I see your HTTP Request? what is the error? route not found?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can either: just define one `Get` method, and have an optional Id Parameter like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(int? id){
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
         //return collection of one item here
    }
    //return collection of all items here
}
```

Or you can have multiple Gets decorated with the ActionName Attribute

```
// GET api/Users
[ActionName("GetAll")]
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()

// GET api/Users/5
[ActionName("Get")]
public User GetUser(int id) // THIS IS NO LONGER IN CONFLICT
```

And then define the routes on your RouteConfig like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Just to clarify`api/Users` and `api/Users/5` are not conflicting. `api/Users/5` and `api/Users/5/UserGroups` are.

Comment: Then use the ActionName approach :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck using Web API v1 and came up w/ the following solution to this.  For all of your general routes, declare the ActionName as "Default".  Then in your route config, set the default action="Default".  This changes your call to /Users/5 to users/5/default and ensures it maps to the right place.  The only problem I've found w/ this solution is that the documentation will show the /Default part of the route.  It looks like you can edit your view to exclude these as this guy did (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353198/4374666).

If you're using v2, it seems like Attribute Routing would be the cleanest way.

```
// GET api/Users/5
[HttpGet, ActionName("Default")]
public User GetUser(int id) // THIS STILL DOES NOT WORK

// GET api/Users/5/UserGroups
[HttpGet, ActionName("usergroups")]
public IEnumerable<UserGroup> GetUserGroups(int id) // THIS WORKS

// ROUTES
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional,
 action = "Default" }
);
```